# Django Admin: Dynamic Auto-Fill a Form Field from Selected Foreign Key's Attributes

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got two simple models that are relevant to the question:

```
class CarMake(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    default_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

class Car(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    make = models.ForeignKey(CarMake)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

When creating or updating a `Car` object in the Django Admin, I'd like the `cost` field to be auto-populated with the `default_cost` of the chosen `CarMake` that is selected from the drop-down.

Currently, I am storing the `cost` as the make's `default_cost` if the field is left blank on saving the object. I'd prefer to do this dynamically when the `make` drop down chooses a value. I assume that the solution would involve some amount of JavaScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want the selection to be updated dynamically you'd have to use JS. Doing this kind of stuff would involve hacking the django admin site. You may be able to get away with just customizing the template to load some JS with and event handler that updates the specific drop-down. However this would be vulnerable to breakage when updating Django (the admin site templates have no guarantee of backwards compatibility). Personally I'd just write a custom view.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and confirming what I was thinking. Not worth the trouble to do a custom view with JS. I'll just stick with what I have for now.